# Linear Regression's coefficient and intercept kept changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science

```
bach_sal = bach['Salary']
masters_sal = masters['Salary']
phd_sal = phd['Salary']
deg_category_sal = [assoc_sal, bach_sal, masters_sal, phd_sal]

x = np.array(assoc['Person'])
y = np.array(assoc_sal)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.7)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x_train.reshape(-1,1),y_train)
print (lr.coef_)
print (lr.intercept_)
```

I received the coefficient and y intercept but everytime I run the code, they change to a different number. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: maybe you could try setting a random seed for your code/where you do your train_test_split. That method randomly selects a % of your data so it would change between runs\

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not set the random_state in the train_test split function. This shuffles the cut for test data on each run and as a result, the coefficient changes slightly.
Set the random_state to an integer to get the same answer over multiple runs.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 0):

This will keep changing until you specify a fixed value of random_state to your train test line number.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

After making this change you might get exact same values. In general, your train and test data will keep on changing until you specify set rows for training and test.